# Django URL not working as expected

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a URL that does not work, for some reason. I get a 404, "'new' could not be found". Here is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^assets/new', 'watershed.views.new_asset', name='new_asset'),
```

There is a lot more in my urls.py but this is the ONLY one that contains the word, "assets" in it. If I change this url to anything/new, it works. If i misspell assets (assettss/new), it works. If I take out the /new and just use "assets", it also works fine. In my views folder I have an __ init __.py which contains the following:

```
from groups import *
from members import *
from leave_group import *
from payments import *
from assets import *
```

I also have an assets.py, which contains the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from watershed.models import Member, Org, OrgToMember, Asset
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def new_asset(request):
    return render(request, 'asset_add.html')
```

I have no idea what Django does not like about assets/new.

UPDATE: Here is my full urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
url(r'^', include('outside.urls')),
url(r'^blog', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^logout', 'watershed.views.logout', name='logout'),
url(r'^register/create', 'watershed.views.create', name='create'),
url(r'^register', 'watershed.views.register', name='register'),
url(r'^translog/(\d+)', 'watershed.views.translog', name='translog'),
url(r'^settings', 'watershed.views.settings', name='settings'),

# Group URIs
url(r'^groups/(\d+)/leave', 'watershed.views.leave_group', name='leave_group'),
url(r'^groups/(\d+)/dissolve', 'watershed.views.dissolve_group', name='dissolve_group'),
url(r'^groups/new', 'watershed.views.add_group_form', name='add_group_form'),
url(r'^groups/(\d+)', 'watershed.views.dashboard', name='dashboard'),
url(r'^groups/add', 'watershed.views.add_group', name='add_group'),
url(r'^groups', 'watershed.views.groups', name='groups'),

# Member URIs
url(r'^members/(\d+)', 'watershed.views.profile', name='profile'),
url(r'^member/login', 'watershed.views.login', name='login'),

# Payments URIs
url(r'^payments', 'watershed.views.payments', name='payments'),

# Asset URIs
url(r'^assets/new', 'watershed.views.new_asset', name='new_asset'),
```

Comment: show some more of your urls.py... the order that they are defined in the file matters. it sounds like you have another url for `assets/` getting matched before `r'^assets/new'` is reached

Comment: urls.py in full, just added

Comment: Probably your problem is here: `url(r'^', include('outside.urls')),` you should use ^$ for the url matcher, what's in outside.urls?

Comment: this line should come last instead of first, it will intercept all the urls and send them to the other urlconf: `url(r'^', include('outside.urls'))` which is likely to cause problems

Comment: @imandrewd `url(r'^$', include('outside.urls'))` would be wrong because then none of the sub urls defined in outside.urls could get matched

Comment: But all the other URLS are working except for the last one. Nothing in my outside.urls even comes close to a matching url for assets/new. Also, I moved it to the bottom and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to turn on additional debugging so that I can see exactly what is going on, other than just throwing a 404?

Comment: I also just removed my outside.urls include to eliminate that possibility altogether, and, I moved assets/new to the top. Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You `new_assets` function containts in `assets.py` file, buy you import this function from `views.py` file. Use this:

```
url(r'^assets/new', 'path.to.assets.new_asset', name='new_asset'),
```

Comment: I can access the new_asset function by either watershed.views.assets.new_asset OR by watershed.views.new_asset - both work. Well, neither work but this is why i'm posting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is that my static url in my settings.py is - wait for it:

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
```

So, clearly, one of those must change.